# init() vs didMove vs sceneDidLoad in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I understand that there are 3 ways to create a scene in SpriteKit, init(), didMove, and sceneDidLoad.
But I can't understand to separate the 3 ways. Reading other questions I understood the order to call is init -> SceneDidLoad -> didMove.

How can I use them to use effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about the order those functions are called in. But only `init(size:)` actually creates a scene.

[init(size:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1520435-init) initializes a new scene object with the given `CGSize` as its bounds. Anything that must be set up prior to the scene becoming visible should happen here. That's the important bit because a newly initialized scene isn't visible to the user until it's presented by a view.

[sceneDidLoad()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1645216-scenedidload) is called as a result of `init(size:)` and can be used to do any more setup required before the scene is presented. `init(size:)` can be called from wherever you want to make a new scene, but `sceneDidLoad()` happens in the scene itself. This is useful for any setup that you want all scenes of this class to use.

[didMove(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519607-didmove) is different because it doesn't have to do with the initialization. This function is called when the scene is presented by a view. Basically, when it becomes visible to the user. UI adjustments and layout for elements *inside* the scene are typically handled here.